# jQuery click inside loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, click, comparison-operators

Trying to achieve with `extractAsset();` the following:

- When clicking `div.clickable`, if `lists[i].id` is >= than it's previous `lists[i].id` (tried .prev() but nothing) then `toggleClass("highlight");`

Ideally if this worked, only list2(id:8) would toggle yellow background.

What I've been trying is commented on the fiddle.

[see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaxjLvgs/)

A working fiddle example is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the values of the .data element html. To get the previous one, use the jquery prev function on the target div.

```
function extractAsset() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    $(".clickable" + [i]).click(function(){         
      if($(this).find('.data').html() >= $(this).prev().find('.data').html())
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    })
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaxjLvgs/1/)

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome!